# show display:none div after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Don't know how to put the question title correctly!
I have a div that is displayed by button click. The problem is that if user goes to next page(by clicking another button) and then come back to the old page the div is not shown because page is refreshed, so user needs to click the button again to see the div.

Is there any way to keep div displayed after button clicked for first time?

```
<div id="tableDiv" style="display:none;" >
<table>
   <td>something</td>
</table>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Show" onClick="showTable()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">         
   function showTable() {
       document.getElementById('tableDiv').style.display = "block";
   }                
</script>
```

Comment: So the "another button" click causes the browser to fetch a whole new page from the server? What kind of server side technology are you using?

Comment: You would need to keep track with localstorage or cookies.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to answer this question, can you please describe the technology stack you are using so we can have a better idea of how best to answer this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the html5 webStorage for this:

`localStorage` does not expire, whereas `sessionStorage` gets deleted when the browser is closed (usage of both is equivalent). The webStorage is support by all major browsers and IE >= 8

**Plain Javascript**

```
function showTable() {
   document.getElementById('tableDiv').style.display = "block";
   localStorage.setItem('show', 'true'); //store state in localStorage
}
```

And check the state onLoad:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var show = localStorage.getItem('show');
    if(show === 'true'){
         document.getElementById('tableDiv').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function showTable() {
    $('#tableDiv').show();
    localStorage.setItem('show', 'true'); //store state in localStorage
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var show = localStorage.getItem('show');
    if(show === 'true'){
        $('#tableDiv').show();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hut65tja/1/)

P.S. To remove an item from the localStorage use

```
localStorage.removeItem('show');
```

**Reference**

[webStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: I tried to use your jQuery code, but it seems that the button doesn't work any more I changed the code to following, still don't work:(  `$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btn").click(function(){...` also the js code shows the table without even clicking the button. do you have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @nana I provided a working example and updated my answer a bit. Since you are using a button for the click event, you may have to use `event.prevenDefault()` when it's inside a form

Comment: still doesn't work! I guess it has something to do with my form as you said. Am I using event.preventDefault() correctly? `$("#btn").click(function(){
          event.preventDefault();
            $('#tableDiv').show();
            localStorage.setItem('show', 'true');
        });`

Comment: @nana you need to pass `event` as a parameter for your click-function. I will update my fiddle

Comment: It's weird! Seems like it just work sometimes. I ran the server first time and it worked, but then after that whenever I restart the server it diplays the table without clicking the button.I also test it with a new project and it worked first time but not since then.I even restarted my computer, doesn't work any more just shows the table without button clicked :(

Comment: Try using `sessionStorage` intead. The `localStorage` will store the state until it is removed. Whereas the `sessionStorage` gets deleted when the Browser is closed. Please see my reference link at the end of my answer

Answer (score 6):

Use localstorage to save the state

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
   function showTable() {
       document.getElementById('tableDiv').style.display = "block";
       localStorage.setItem('showTable', true);  //set flag   
   }

   function hideTable() {
       document.getElementById('tableDiv').style.display = "none";
       localStorage.removeItem('showTable');  //remove key   
   }

   if (localStorage.getItem('showTable')) {  //see if flag is set (returns undefined if not set)
       showTable();   //if set show table
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your best option is to use the `location.hash` as a JavaScript Router. Basically modify the hash, watch for hash changes and if the hash is equal to a specific value do something. Then when the used leaves and hits "back", they will come back to the page with the previous hash, in which case you can detect which version of the page they were on and recreate it.

```
<div id="tableDiv" style="display:none;" >
  <table>
    <td>something</td>
  </table>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Show" onClick="showTable()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function showTable(){
    location.hash = "#show"; // sets hash to #show, which will fire onhaschange event which its handler is hashRouter()
  }
  function hashRouter(){
    if(window.hash == "#show"){ // shows table if hash is #show
      document.getElementById('tableDiv').style.display = "block";
    }
  }
  window.onhashchange = hashRouter; // Calls when hash is changed.
  window.onload = hashRouter; // Calls when page loads;
</script>
```

There are many other options such as cookies or localstorage.

Check out this plugin:

https://github.com/addcms/addHashRouter

Using this solution you might do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="tableDiv" style="display:none;">
  <table>
    <td>something</td>
  </table>
</div>
<a href='#show'>Show Table</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$add.UI.hashRouter.add("show", function(){
    document.getElementById('tableDiv').style.display = "block";
});
```

And then if they hit the "back button" after navigating away from the page it will still appear, and if they hit the back button after showing the table it will not "rehide" it, unless you added this:

**HTML**

```
<a href='#hide'>Hide Table</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$add.UI.hashRouter.add("hide", function(){
    document.getElementById('tableDiv').style.display = "none";
});
```

And then you can use show/hide buttons with browser navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Using @DustinPoissant's answer, I've made something a little bit easier.

You can use the selector `:target` to style the element, and save you some code.

Like this:

```
<style>
    #tableDiv {display:none;}
    #tableDiv:target {display:block!important;}
</style>

<div id="tableDiv">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>something</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Show" onClick="showTable()"/>
<input type="button" value="Hide" onClick="hideTable()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function showTable() {
       location.hash='tableDiv';
   }
   function hideTable() {
       location.hash='';
   }
</script>
```

The `:target` selector will match when the 'hash' on your address matches the id of that element.

Comment: Using important is a bad bad idea.

Comment: @epascarello Depending on the situation. The only change is that it is enforcing the style. But if you use Javascript to change it, it will work anyway. So, there is no problem here.

Comment: I like it, great answer, its like my answer but more specific to just showing/hiding elements whereas my answer can be used to a multitude of things. This is great, less code and works great. and @epascarello I use ``!important`` all the time, never ran into an issue, please explain why you think its a bad idea instead of stating it as such.

Comment: Because !important is a poor mans approach to not dealing with CSS Specificity correctly.

Comment: @epascarello If you want, you can try without the `!important` there. I give no guarantee that it will work under **ANY** circunstance. This way, I'm sure the code will work regardless of whatever is thrown there.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it with a cookie.
there's a good lightweight [jquery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) for this.

so set a cookie:

```
$.cookie("var", "10");
```

to get the cookie:

```
$.cookie("var");
```

to delete the cookie:

```
$.cookie("var", null);
```

and now you can do something like:

```
function showTable() {
    document.getElementById('tableDiv').style.display = "block";
    $.cookie("var", "1");
}

function leaveButtonOpen(){
    if($.cookie("var") == 1){
        document.getElementById('tableDiv').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure, but is this a jQuery-core feature yet ?

Comment: ah i forgot to mention.. you need a lightweight jquery plugin. edited and thanks