# How to retain value of the jQuery function after the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have small function:

```
$('input#TT_topiclist_fontsize.type-form').on('keyup', both);

function both(){
  window.opener.$('#header-site-description h1').css('fontSize', this.value + 'px');
}
```

So when I in input field type in desired font size (some number), the function works, but after page reload or refresh it does not work although the number is still there in input field. So again i need to type some number to get working funciton.

My question is how to retain value of the jQuery function after the page is reloaded ?

Thank you

Comment: Look into cookies and local storage.

Comment: can you tell me how please ?

Comment: @Bundyboy [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28481303/4202224) is an example that could be helpful to you

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API to get started with localStorage