# JQuery - remember CSS style

Tags: jquery, css

I've done some style changing with JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#green').click(function (){
   style1 = $('link[href="style1.css"]').attr('href','style2.css');
});
$('#gray').click(function (){
   style2 = $('link[href="style2.css"]').attr('href','style1.css');
});
});
```

So, It's simple to change it with buttons. For example, I've got style1 with bg-color: green, and style2 with color gray.

If someone click on button green, how Can i keep it when he going into my web app? I mean next page, refreshing, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show display:none div after refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481221/show-displaynone-div-after-refresh)

Comment: take a look at localStorage -- when you set the style, simply save the value into localStorage, then when you first load the page, retrieve that value and use it to set the appropriate style.

Comment: Look into cookies.

Comment: Yup. thanks guys for tips, I did it with local Storage

Answer (score 2):

you can do so [using `cookies`](https://www.sitepoint.com/eat-those-cookies-with-jquery/)

> Cookies are the most used technology for storing data on the client side. My previous article, How to Deal with Cookies in JavaScript, explained how to perform CRUD operations with cookies using raw JavaScript. This article turns to jQuery, and will guide you through the use of jquery.cookie, a plugin which makes cookie processing simple.

1. Installing jquery.cookie

   `<head>
      <script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    </head>`
2. Initialising cookies

   `$.cookie("style", style1);`
3. Retrieving Cookies on second page :

   ```
   console.debug($.cookie("style"));
   ```

[Official documentation](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by Using Globe Variable
**Suppose it is your landing page**

```
<script>
var defaultStyleSheet = "style2.css";

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#green').click(function (){
defaultStyleSheet = 'style2.css';
  $('link[href="style1.css"]').attr('href',defaultStyleSheet );
});
$('#gray').click(function (){
defaultStyleSheet = 'style1.css';
 $('link[href="style2.css"]').attr('href',defaultStyleSheet );
});
}); 
</script>
```

**NOW you have to access that Stylesheet for other page**

```
 $(document).on('load ready',function(){
  $('link[href="style2.css"]').attr('href',defaultStyleSheet );
});
```

Now **defaultStylesheet** has the last value you set and stylesheet will be loaded accordingly.

Comment: A global JS variable is not going to persist across page views/loads.