# Window.onload function with arguments to show display: none img after refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fav-icon on each card (carrousel of gifs) that is display and hidden by button click.And I need that if the users clicks the fav icon stays active even if the page refresh. I'm guiding from this question [show display:none div after refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481221/show-displaynone-div-after-refresh) but my code is a little bit different (Vanilla JS and Template literals):

**Section creating the template for every card**

```
const loadData = (data) => {
    let trendSection = document.querySelector('.card-container')
    let content = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        content += `
                    <img class="image-card" src="${data[i].images.downsized.url}">
                    <div class="custom-overlay-icons">
                        <a type="button"><img class="image_on" src="assets/images/icon-fav.svg" onClick="likeCard('${[i]}')"><img id="fav-active${[i]}" src="assets/images/icon-fav-active.svg"></a>
                       //The display of fav-active img is none by default in CSS
                    </div>`
    }
    trendSection.innerHTML = content
}
```

**Section to get the icon to change on click**

```
window.likeCard = (index) => {
let image = document.getElementById('fav-active' + i)
    if (!image.style.display || image.style.display === 'none') {
        image.style.display = 'block'
        localStorage.setItem('show');
    } else {
        image.style.display = 'none'
        localStorage.removeItem('show');
    }
}
```

Finnally, the problem, is that I dont know how and where to implement the function that the checks the state onLoad  like they porpuse on the solution if I need the index variable, I got these:

```
window.onload = function(i) {
    let show = localStorage.getItem('show');
    if(show === 'true'){
         document.getElementById('fav-active' + i).style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

I don't know If I was clear but let me know if something does'nt make sense

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem):

> The setItem() method of the Storage interface, when passed a key name and value, will add that key to the given Storage object, or update that key's value if it already exists.

The Syntax:

> storage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);

##### The Problem

You are trying to store the `show` variable in the localStorage, but you didn't pass any `keyValue` to it. so in `onload` event handler, the show variable is `undefined`.

##### The Solution:

set the `show` item properly in `likeCard` event handler:

```
if (!image.style.display || image.style.display === 'none') {
    image.style.display = 'block'
    localStorage.setItem('show', true);  // or false as your desire
} else {
    image.style.display = 'none'
    localStorage.removeItem('show', false); // or true as your desire
}
```

##### Optional

since the result of `let show = localStorage.getItem('show')` is only booleans (true/false), you can remove the comparison from the `if` block in the `onload` handler:

```
window.onload = function(event) {
    let show = localStorage.getItem('show');
    if(show) { // ------> if (true) / if(false)
         document.getElementById('fav-active').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense! However, still dont know  how and where to implement the onload function. I mean, from where this function will found the index (i) parameter?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event @Nataly

Comment: I copied your implementation to demonstrate the other issue (with localStorage) and now I update my answer with the proper event on `onload` method.  You can add `window.onload`  anywhere on your `script` tag. but if you want to change the specific item with a button, it needs a different approach and might you need to ask about it in another question. @Nataly